# In python Cross-validation in neural network with multi class labes in target variable

Tags: python, neural-network, cross-validation

hey everyone can you please help me to find the solution of this problem
i want to apply cross validation in  neural networks  but it is showing nan values in output,
here is my codes

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
# create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=10, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Comment: have you fit the model?

Comment: @Fasty yes i had done fit even i also calculate accuracy and auc_roc score also  but i got problem only in cross validation.

Comment: Can you just give the error output.?. Whats the scoring pararmeter here in cross_val_score function?

Comment: @Fasty there is no error but there is also no values  this is output==  Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 1/10
Baseline: nan% (nan%)

​

Comment: @Fasty  Baseline: nan% (nan%)    this is problem  i am expecting some values